# Why appear "can't assign to function call" error?

Tags: python

I use dijkstra algorithm and make shortest_subway_route python code.

It's main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = Graph() #class define add_node,add_egde

    subway() #def use add_node,add_egde
    sub = transkor() #def read .txt and make Dictionary

    s=int(input("start>>")) #input subway_number
    d=int(input("end>>")) #input subway_number

    R=shortest_path(graph, s, d) #def view how to use subway route

    sub_num =R['return1']

    subkor = list()
    num = 0
    for s in sub_num :
        kor = sub[s]
        subkor[num] = kor
        num+=1

    print(sub_kor)    
    print("time =",R['return0'])
```

R['return1'] is list of subwaynumbers

I tried to save the subway number in Korean.
But "subkor[num] = kor" is list assignment index out of range error.

What can I do?
[image]

I also use "subkor.append(num) = kor" but can't assign to function call error

Comment: I also used "subkor.append(num) = kor" can't assign to function call error

Comment: You don't need the `if __name__ == '__main__':` as an umbrella for a toplevel script. That is just a common pattern for a module defining several fucntins and classes that can have a stand alone use, or be imported as part of another program

Comment: Strange, I'd expect `subkor.append(num) = kor` to crash with `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` rather than "list assignment out of range".

Comment: (therefore, you can just add this code to another .py file and import the things that are defined in this one)

Comment: what do you expect subkor.append(num) = kor to actually do?